# How can I count the number of devices connected via bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to connect 4 devices via Bluetooth in my app and after 4 devices are connected I want to stop any more devices to get connected.To do this I need to know the number of connected devices.

How can I find the number of connected devices programmatically?

Comment: What "app" is that? Did you create an app? We need a little more info from you I think

Comment: Yes,I created an app...a game to be exact.I created a card game and want to add bluetooth multiplayer in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getBondedDevices()` returns a set of currently paired devices
   you can get the number of connected devices from its `size()`

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> devices =  bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
//deviceS.size()
```

Answer (score 0):

BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set devices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();

```
    if (devices.size() == 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "  No paired devices : ");
    }
    else if (devices.size() > 1) {

        Log.i(TAG, "  Too many paired devices : " + devices.size() );

        // Loop and dump the paired devices
        for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
            Log.i(TAG, "  Device: " + device.getName() + ", " + device);
            Log.i(TAG, "  Address: " + device.getAddress() + ", " + device);
        }
    }
    else {
        retVal = devices.iterator().next().getAddress();
    }
```